# I need help on a findPath algorithm on TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to answer an exercise which ask to code a findPath function in TypeScript.
This is guidelines :

Write a function called findPath which return path size to exit of a given cave in binary matrix
Entry coordinates (begin) and exit coordinates (end) and cave map (matrix) will be given as arguments
A path can be built only if the cell has a value equal to 1.
You can only move one cell at a time, vertically or horizontally.
Diagonal moves are forbidden.
The edges of the matrix are not traversing
The arguments will always correspond to a valid matrix.
A matrix will always contain a single solution and this solution will always be valid.

findPath function will be prototyped as this

```
type Coordinate = [number, number]
type Matrix = number[][]
type FindPathFn = (begin: Coordinate, end: Coordinate, matrix: Matrix) => number
```

Do you think that you can help me please ?

I have try that :

```
type Coordinate = [number, number]
type Matrix = number[][]
type FindPathFn = (begin: Coordinate, end: Coordinate, matrix: Matrix) => number

export const findPath: FindPathFn = (begin, end, matrix) => {
  const ROWS = matrix.length;
  const COLS = matrix[0].length;
  const visited = new Array<boolean>(ROWS * COLS).fill(false);

  const dfs = (row: number, col: number, distance: number): number => {
    if (row < 0 || row >= ROWS || col < 0 || col >= COLS || visited[row * COLS + col] || matrix[row][col] !== 1) {
      return -1;
    }

    visited[row * COLS + col] = true;

    if (row === end[0] && col === end[1]) {
      return distance;
    }

    const up = dfs(row - 1, col, distance + 1);
    if (up !== -1) return up;

    const down = dfs(row + 1, col, distance + 1);
    if (down !== -1) return down;

    const left = dfs(row, col - 1, distance + 1);
    if (left !== -1) return left;

    const right = dfs(row, col + 1, distance + 1);
    if (right !== -1) return right;

    return -1;
  };

  return dfs(begin[0], begin[1], 0);
};
```

Comment: You'll get better and faster answers if you ask a specific question, like which part of the algorithm you're having trouble with, what you've tried, what you expect to happen, and what isn't happening. Did you write this code?

Comment: I'm very in difficult with these exercise but I'm very blocked about this.
 I had try lot of possibilities under 6 or 7 weeks but my code doesn't match to test fixed by platform.

My code give a return of -1 to all tests

Comment: This isn't a good question for Stackoverflow because it is not focused, and there are probably many issues with your code. Get in the habit of debugging your own code with `console.log()`. For example, if your function is returning `-1`, did you try to figure out why? Which one of the conditions in the `if` statement is true, causing you to `return -1`? And is that part of the if statement _supposed_ to be true?

Comment: As a head start, this check `matrix[row][col] !== 1` is checking if the cell at the coordinate isn't 1, then exit. So the very first thing your code does is check if the start location cell is NOT 1, then exits. The start location cell should always be zero, since it has to be an open space. So the if statement will immediately exit your algorithm without trying to search for anything.